# Save cyrillic symbols in a txt file in C

Tags: c, text, save, cyrillic

I am relatively new in C.

The following program, that I will paste here is just illustrative for my question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char letters[7];
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    printf("letters:\n");
    gets(letters);
    printf("%c",letters[0]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[1]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[2]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[3]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[4]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[5]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[6]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(letters));

    FILE*fptr;
    fptr=fopen("combo.txt", "w");

    for(a=0;a<=sizeof(letters)-1;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<=sizeof(letters)-1;b++)
        {
            for(c=0;c<=sizeof(letters)-1;c++)
            {
                for(d=0;d<=sizeof(letters)-1;d++)
                {
                    for(e=0;e<=sizeof(letters)-1;e++)
                    {
                        for(f=0;f<=sizeof(letters)-1;f++)
                        {
                            for(g=0;g<=sizeof(letters)-1;g++)
                            {
                                if (!(a==b||a==c||a==d||a==e||a==f||a==g||
                                            b==c||b==d||b==e||b==f||b==g||
                                                  c==d||c==e||c==f||c==g||
                                                        d==e||d==f||d==g||
                                                              e==f||e==g||
                                                                    f==g))
                                {
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[a]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[b]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[c]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[d]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[e]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[f]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[g]);

                                    fprintf(fptr,"\n");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The program does:

- read the keyboard input as a string
- save it into a string called
  "letters"
- print into the console every element on a new line
- print the length of the string two lines below
- combine the symbols in every possible way, except repeating a symbol behind a certain position twice in a word and writes the combo into a file "combo.txt".

**My question is, can I do this with cyrillic symbols, not only in latin letters?**

**If it is possible (I believe it is), what shall I add or change in my code?**

Comment: I addition, I have to mention, that I checked all the info, I have found about my question, but I didn't manage to answer it. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=cyrillic%20txt

Comment: Never ***ever*** use `gets`. It's a dangerous function, that has even been removed from the C specification.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Can you suggest a substitute of `gets`? I am ready to hear any remarks, regarding my code. :) Answers to my questions are also highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Use `fgets()` with `stdin`

Comment: Added `#include <stdin.h>` on the bottom and substituted `gets` with `fgets` - didn't compile. The error is `fatal error: stdin.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: If your enter `"abcdefg"` then that's 7 characters, plus the null-character at the end. That's 8 bytes. So you should declare `char letters[8]`, and maybe use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`!

Comment: Where did you get the idea to try to `#include <stdin.h>`? That doesn't exist. `fgets()` is a function declared in `stdio.h` and the filestream `stdin` is defined there as well.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, when I declare length of 6, the last symbol is lost after the creation of the txt file.

Comment: @torstenvl, I read abut `fgets` right now, so I believe, I will manage to apply your advice soon. :)

Comment: I said ***8*** bytes, not 6. `char letters[8]; fgets(letters, sizeof(letters), stdin);for(int i = 0; i < strlen(letters); i++) printf("%c\n", letters[i]);`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, the above code declares 8 bytes, including the zero index, but the last byte is lost after the line that creates the file. Initially I made the program with `letters[6]` and inserted 7 characters "asdfghj" for example. In the file the combinations are between "asfgh' ". The "j" was replaced with " ' ". Try it out. :)

Comment: Well don't stick 8 characters in to buffer size 6. Normally I would declare buffer size 100 since I have lots more memory on my computer. You need one extra by for the null-character at the end. You don't see the null-character when you print the string but it's there.

Comment: I'm with @BarmakShemirani on this, your declaration reads `char letters[7]`, this will hold 6 characters plus a NUL-character (with ASCII code 0, also notice NUL, not NULL). If you're not trying to cause memory leaks, add an extra element and manually initialise it to `0` (or character `'\0'`). In addition, include `#include <string.h>` and use `strlen(letters)` instead of `sizeof(...)`. Also, do `for (x=0; x<strlen(letters); x++)` instead of `x<=sizeof(letters)-1`. The latter is dangerous, one misuse and you've got a memory leak. Read on C-string and NUL-termination and why it's used...

Comment: Having said the above, your array can happily hold 7 characters since C does not care, but the standard functions (e.g. `printf(...)` and the like) do care for the NUL character. If you print each character manually keeping track of the position in the string, you're fine not using a NUL-terminated string, but then you'll have to read the whole string manually: one character at a time. It's usually far less work and makes a portable code if you simply use the NUL-terminator and use standard functions with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Cyrillic characters, yes. However, that's going to require some learning about a fairly complex topic.

Internationalizing your programs requires understanding locales, character sets, and encodings. The modern way of trying to deal with these issues is with a character set called Unicode, usually in an encoding called UTF-8 (if you're on Unix-like operating systems). On Windows, you're more likely to encounter UTF-16.

I recommend you start here: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I am starting this as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

The improved program with `fgets` instead of `gets`, looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char letters[7];
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g;

    printf("letters:\n");
    //gets(letters);

    fgets(letters,8,stdin);

    printf("%c",letters[0]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[1]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[2]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[3]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[4]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[5]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c",letters[6]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(letters));

    FILE*fptr;
    fptr=fopen("combo.txt", "w");

    for(a=0;a<=sizeof(letters)-1;a++)
    {
        for(b=0;b<=sizeof(letters)-1;b++)
        {
            for(c=0;c<=sizeof(letters)-1;c++)
            {
                for(d=0;d<=sizeof(letters)-1;d++)
                {
                    for(e=0;e<=sizeof(letters)-1;e++)
                    {
                        for(f=0;f<=sizeof(letters)-1;f++)
                        {
                            for(g=0;g<=sizeof(letters)-1;g++)
                            {
                                if (!(a==b||a==c||a==d||a==e||a==f||a==g||
                                            b==c||b==d||b==e||b==f||b==g||
                                                  c==d||c==e||c==f||c==g||
                                                        d==e||d==f||d==g||
                                                              e==f||e==g||
                                                                    f==g))
                                {
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[a]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[b]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[c]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[d]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[e]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[f]);
                                    fprintf(fptr,"%c",letters[g]);

                                    fprintf(fptr,"\n");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, the problem still is on the line. If I manage to solve it before someone else, I will post a solution here. :)

Comment: What makes you think you can safely `fgets()` eight bytes into a seven-byte buffer?